# jQuery cycle plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

how can I set multiple timeout?
pls help me...

`timeout:'1000, 2000, 3000'`  this is not working.

Comment: Nick Craver has a great answer to a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3075104/538962

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the `timeout` property, you should use [`timeoutFn`](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/timeout.html) and define there a function that returns the number of milliseconds to wait for the next slide.

For example if you have only 3 slides and you want those 3 timeouts you used (1000, 2000, 3000), then I assume that after the last timeout you want use the first timeout again (each picture have time to stay on screen). So in that case the code would simply be:

```
$('#s1').cycle({
    timeoutFn: function (curr, next, opts, isForward) {
        return (opts.currSlide + 1) * 1000;
    }
});
```

On the other hand, if you want to set more than 3 slides, then you can use your own properties (like an array and a counter) and use them inside the function to calculate the corresponding timeout:

```
$('#s1').cycle({
    timeoutFn: function(currElement, nextElement, opts, isForward) {
        opts.myTimeoutCount = (opts.myTimeoutCount + 1) % opts.myTimeouts.length;
        return opts.myTimeouts[opts.myTimeoutCount];
    },
    myTimeouts: [1000, 2000, 3000],
    myTimeoutCount: 0
});
```

And at last, if don't want to show any other slide after the last timeout then you should simply use the `autostop` & `autostopCount` properties:

```
$('#s1').cycle({
    autostop: true,
    autostopCount: 3,
    timeoutFn: function (curr, next, opts, isForward) {
        return (opts.currSlide + 1) * 1000;
    }
});
```